# Delta Lake change data feed - delete, vacuum, read - java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: delta-lake, change-data-capture

I used the following to write to google cloud storage

```
df.write.format("delta").partitionBy("g","p").option("delta.enableChangeDataFeed", "true").mode("append").save(path)
```

And then I inserted data in versions 1,2,3,4.
I deleted some of the data in version 5.

Ran

```
deltaTable.vacuum(8)
```

I tried to read starting Version 3

```
spark.read.format("delta")
  .option("readChangeFeed", "true")
  .option("startingVersion", 3)
  .load(path)
```

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
File not found: gs://xxx/yyy.snappy.parquet
It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate
the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by
recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.

I deleted the cluster and tried to read again. Same issue. Why is it looking for the vacuumed files?

I expected to see all the data inserted starting version 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the setting worked!
spark.sql.files.ignoreMissingFiles ->true

Answer (score 0):

When running `deltaTable.vacuum(8)`, please note that you're removing the files that are more than 8 hours old. Even if you had deleted version 5 of the table, if the files for version 3 are older than 8 hours, then the only files that would be  available are the most current version (in this case version 4).

Comment: Hi Denny, All the data in versions 1-5 are older than 8 hours at the time of vacuum. Note that
spark.read.format("delta").load(path) 
loads all the data from version 1-4 minus deleted data. Something is wrong with CDC(change data capture) in delta lake(2.1.0)

Comment: Okay, a bit of a disconnect here - if all the data files in version 1-5 are older than 8h, then all of the files, except for the most current table, would have been removed when you run the vacuum.  This would be the reason why CDC would not work.

Comment: I updated my description. I only deleted some of the data(most recent data) in version 5. Sorry about the confusion